# Changing home directory path with usermod doesn't work

Tags: partition, home, gparted, move

When I try to use this command (as root)

`# usermod -d /media/erez -m erez`

I get

> usermod: user erez is currently used by process <number>

Lot of examples on this issue but none of them mentioned this problem. I hope I am missing a basic thing here.
I'm really trying to avoid USB boot (when I tried, I get "Boot error" and couldn't proceed from there).

- Some background:

I use dual boot on my laptop. (I keep Windows just in case .. =] ).
I've create 3 partition:

1. root - 8 Giga
2. SWAP - 2 Giga
3. some ntfs - 25 Giga (that supposed to be for data, /home etc. )

My */home* directory seems to be linked to the **wrong** partition (to the root), instead of the *ntfs*. [ I don't know for sure, but from reading, it happened due to adding another user. But again, maybe just a bad installation...]

With gparted, There is a 'key' sign next to the 2 partitions I've created (the root and the ntfs). Is it part of the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Command `usermod` fails if the said user has process(es) running under the same username, regardless what you are trying to modify in this account. You either have to kill all processes owned by this user (in a corporate environment, I need to warn you , NOT to do that) or just edit the `/etc/passwd` file and change whatever you need and the next time the user logs in from a new session, he or she will have the new settings.

Comment: No change. Is this right? I edit the `/etc/passwd` file based on this link (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-the-best-way-to-edit-etcpasswd-shadow-and-group-files.html), and type the command on another terminal.

Comment: `vipw` is a safer way of editing the `/etc/passwd` file on busier systems, but it can be used for any. When you say "_No change_", what kind of a change were you expecting ??